# data sync in a active-passive pacemaker cluster

Tags: synchronization, pacemaker

I'm planning to use `pacemaker` with `corosync` and `pcs` to provide HA in a active-passive cluster for our two front end servers serving a perl application. I have configured resources for the service IP, Apache the application daemon and what I still need to do - configure replication. That means, I need to configure replication that depending which node is the active one it will sync the whole /opt/application directory to the passive node. How to achieve this is the bast way? Both frontends are ESX VM's.

Thank you!

Comment: Sync from where? If you mean sync from the other node, this is not a good idea, as it depends on the other node being up. If the other node just dies all of a sudden, then you have no access to the data.

Comment: Does it even make sense to sync the application directories of both nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRBD should work for this. There are plenty of tutorials out there describing how to configure a Pacemaker, Corosync, and DRBD cluster stack.

DRBD replicates an entire block device, so you'd either add an additional disk to your VMs, cut some extra space out of an LVM volume group for a new LV, or partition your disk.

Comment: if I will use a new LV do I need to move the /opt/myapp to the new volume group or hos is this supposed to work. I struggle to understand it.

Comment: You'd move `/opt/myapp/` onto the new DRBD device. You could then use Pacemaker to mount the DRBD device to `/opt/myapp`. But, you could also mount DRBD anywhere else and use symlinks. Take a look at the DRBD users guide for more general info: https://docs.linbit.com/docs/users-guide-9.0/#p-work

Comment: @MattKereczman thank you Matt. I will  definitely read the user guide! So just to make sure I got it correct. I could also create symlinks from /opt/myapp/ to /myapp/sync that resides on a LV that is the new DRBD device, correct?

Comment: If you're going to put LVM on top of the DRBD device, yes. I'd recommend LVM under DRBD, and then you'd only want to access the DRBD block device, and not the underlying LVM.

Comment: @MattKereczman ok I got it now. Two last questions. This are ESX Vm's. Is there any other agent than das vmware_fence_soap fencing that can be used for fencing or is it the only option when dealing whith ESX VM? The second question would if it there's any other way than using DRBD? Like rsync resource agent or anything like that ? Could you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Answer 1) Unfortunately, yes. VMware is kind of a moving target for the fence-agents, and finding an agent that supports your version, can be problematic. With 3 nodes, DRBD can use it's own quorum feature (see users guide linked above) to prevent data divergence. Answer 2) I've not used rsync to automatically keep things in sync between two nodes, but I know that csync2 was designed for exactly that: https://github.com/LINBIT/csync2

Comment: @MattKereczman Thank you Matt. You helped me a lot so fat (sorry that I'm unable to up vote your comments - apparently I'm missing reputation points).  When you say it can problematic, that I'm wondering how much `vmware_fence_soap fencing` is appropriate for production. I mean in many organisations the VMware "stuff" is handled by different department and   it might be, as far I understand that an ESX update might make the fencing unstable or even unusable. Is there any documentation describing wich version supports what ? Couldn't find it. Thanks !

Comment: There's no official list that I'm aware of saying which fence-agent supports which version of VMware. You might want to send an email into the ClusterLab's users mailing list (https://lists.clusterlabs.org/mailman/listinfo/users) asking if anyone has success with the agent and your specific version of VMware, or jump into the #clusterlabs IRC channel on Freenode, but definitely give it a try first! It may just work with your version, or you'll be able to ask a more direct question.

Comment: @MattKereczman Thank you Matt. I highly appreciate all of your help! Have a great day and keep doing the great job you do!

Comment: Will do, @yesOrMaybeWhatever! Consider marking the question as answered if you think it was helpful!